# What is a good workflow with Visual Studio when writing a hot-swappable dll in C?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, hotswap

I have a Visual Studio solution with an executable and a hot-swappable dll (plugin). The executable runs a file system monitor in the directory where the dll is built and when a new version is generated, it reloads it and continues working with it. One of the crucial things here is that the executable state is preserved between reloads of the dll.

Now this works fine if I run the program without debugging (Ctrl-F5) and then just build when I have changes in the dll code. The dll is reloaded, the new functionality executed, and it's a charm. The problem is when I want to debug the dll.

Unfortunately Visual Studio doesn't allow me to build while debugging. So the only thing that does work is if I run without debugging and then periodically attach and detach the debugger from the process when I make changes and want to debug the dll. This is pretty cumbersome. Especially when I want to debug the plugin init function. In such case I have to add a break in the executable before calling it (say a message box: "Plugin loaded, but `init` not called. Attach to process now if you want to add breakpoints in `init`).

Is there a Visual Studio workflow where I can skip the constant manual reattaching to the process?

(Xcode with its explicit target selection, for example, does allow me the dream workflow, where everything just works and I can build the .dylib while debugging, without explicitly reattaching the debugger to the process. `init` breakpoints working and all)

Comment: I have exactly the workflow you are describing. Including filesystem watcher to capture changes in source code, then compile the debug DLL outside of MSVS using CL.exe. MSVS automatically allows me to set breakpoints and debug the hot-swapable DLL code. I'm using MSVS-2015.

Comment: The only problem I ran into initially was that MSVS-2015 was locking the .pdb file and never unlocking. And I have solved that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427425/how-to-force-visual-studio-2015-to-unlock-pdb-file-after-freelibrary-call/ . Now the system works completely as you are describing. Mo manual reattaching of debugger.

Comment: What do you mean by - Visual Studio doesn't allow to build while debugging?

Comment: @JBeurer, stop at a breakpoint, change code, press ctrl-shift-b. A prompt pops up telling you that it needs to stop the debugging to build the program.

Comment: I assume here you're talking about the hot-swappable DLL code. Ctrl-shift-b builds the solution. The hot swappable source files CAN be a part of the MSVS solution (visible in solution explorer), BUT they are not built by visual studio (as in marked item type: does not participate in build). Naturally MSVS hotkey ctrl-shift-b cannot work here. When I want to commit changes in hot-swappable portion of the codebase I simply press Ctrl-S (for save) for the source file in visual studio. File system event arrives and the app externally calls CL.exe to compile the changed files and reloads the DLL.

Comment: ^^^ The hot-swappable portion of the codebase is debug-able and change-able at run-time in visual studio, with active-breakpoints using this method. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'll try building externally, thanks