# How to force Visual Studio 2015 to unlock .PDB file after FreeLibrary call?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, pdb-files, hotswap

After loading a DLL library using `LoadLibrary("file.dll")` visual studio also opens and locks `file.pdb`.

The problem is - the `file.pdb` is kept locked even after calling `FreeLibrary(...)`.

It is necessary to recompile `file.dll` and reload it once again (*externally, outside of MSVS*, using `CL.exe`), but the compilation fails because `file.pdb` is still locked.

How to make Visual Studio 2015 release the file lock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coincidentally I've stumbled upon a solution to this:

Go to `Tools -> Options` then `Debugging -> General`, then turn on `Use Native Compatibility Mode`.

This fixes the issue (*e.g. .pdb file is unlocked after unloading .dll now*).

I've no idea why, as I can't find the documentation for `Use Native Compatibility Mode`.

Comment: It is a VS2015 setting, it forces the debugger to use an older debugging engine.  The one used in VS2013.  Sensible setting the new engine is quite buggy.  Somebody ought to file a bug at connect.microsoft.com about this, I'll volunteer you.

Comment: @HansPassant There was a similar bug filed for MSVS 2013, and it's marked closed as in "Won't fix" https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1026184/visual-studio-keeps-locking-the-pdb-file-even-after-the-dll-is-released-using-freelibrary . So I didn't even bother. There's also an interesting comment from Andrew Hall @ MSFT: "Unfortunately the Visual Studio debugger has never supported unloading a pdb when the binary is unloaded from the process, it has always required that debugging be stopped. " Perhaps it has been changed?

Comment: In VS 2019 there's only _Use Managed Compatibility Mode_